# Search Query Score Details in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a program in which, I have to search a given string in a Table(My SQL DB).
And the search query checks whether any matching string is found. It gives me the Search score of the given string by searching against a field in a table.

Here I'm not getting or unable to understand the score it gives me back as the score is not same or not linear.

**Is there any way to limit the search score or make it linear or understandable?**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by linear, but you can get a better understanding of scoring by reviewing how [Lucene calculates scores](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) in general and by using elasticsearch [Explain API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/explain.html) to see how scores were calculated for your particular query and data.

Comment: Actually I wanted to set a cut off value...so if the searched string's value is like more than the cut off then i will do some operations on the entered string else nothing...but i don't know exactly what should be the cut off..because the search score returned by the query is not same all the time or in case of exact match of the entered string or no single match..

Comment: maybe you mean [min-score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-min-score.html)?